# How to convert from a list of string to a list of int in array in python

Tags: python

```
a= pd.DataFrame({"A": [['1','2'], '2','3']}).to_numpy()
```

I want to get `a = {"A": [[1, 2], 2, 3]}`
I cannot use astype for the list in array

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question. I'm not sure the answers below are answering your question. Do you want to convert `{"A": [["1", "2"], "2", "3"]}` to `{"A": [[1, 2], 2, 3]}`?

Answer (score 0):

```
 df.apply(lambda x: int(x), index=['A', ]), axis=1)
```

the conversion is done with casting the string to int, i.e. `'3'` to `int('3')`

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to convert from `a = [['1', '2'], '2', '3']` to `a = [[1, 2], 2, 3]`, or is the pandas bit important?

If it's from your pandas start point, the following works.

```
import pandas as pd

# Starting point
a = pd.DataFrame({"A": [['1','2'], '2','3']})

# Iterate over rows in dataframe
for index, row in a.iterrows():
    # If row contains a list
    if isinstance(row[0], list):
        # Convert each entry in list from string to int
        a.loc[index, 'A'] = [int(val) for val in row[0]] 
    else: 
        a.loc[index, 'A'] = int(row)

a = a.to_dict(orient='list')
print(a)
# {'A': [[1, 2], 2, 3]}
```

If you just wanted from `a = [['1', '2'], '2', '3']` to `a = [[1, 2], 2, 3]`:

```
a = [['1', '2'], '2', '3']
a = [list(map(int, x)) if isinstance(x, list) else int(x) for x in a]
print(a)
# [[1, 2], 2, 3]
```